# Give a user the right language

Tags: javascript, php, html, seo

The webside I am working on, offers english and german content. I want to show the user the right language.

Situation example:

So when someone come to/visits:

```
www.example.de
www.example.ch
www.example.at
```

The language should be German.

But if someone comes to:

```
www.example.com
```

I am asking first via javascript if the browser language is German and if so, 

I am redirecting to the `.de` domain. if not, the website is in english.

Is this the best way to do so? Also for SEO Purposes? Does anyone has a better idea? I know there is also a way to do it with php, is this better?

Here is the code I am redirecting with:

```
$.browserLanguage(function(language, acceptHeader) {
    if (language == "German") {
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.at"
});
```

Comment: Are they all resolving to the same code? Why cant you just check the domain in PHP and serve accordingly?

Comment: I wouldn't redirect at all, maybe just show a hint with a link in the top bar, so the user can choose this for themselves. Maybe they have a good reason to visit the site in another language. If they visit the site more often, they will probably remember or bookmark the right url. If they come through a search engine, they will probably have found the right version because of the language of the search terms, and if they do for whatever reason land on the wrong version, you can hint them to the other version, without forcing them.

Comment: Well, the problem is, many people might come to my side, because of Anglicisms keywords and then the wrong page will be shown. I am giving the possibility, to change the language. I have just seen on Google Analytics that many people are leaving the page after less then 1 Second, because they are not searching for the way to change the language. That's why I want to give them the right language in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For SEO purposes, it's important that all those domains are linked somehow from the main site (a little 'choose language' section with flags it's ok, those are links for the crawler), because the crawlers usually don't execute javascript.

You don't have to execute Javascript on client side to check the preferred language of the client. You can do that on server side reading 'Accept-Language' HTTP header which looks like that:

> Accept-Language   en,de;q=0.5

In that case, English is preferred, and German is 2nd (q=0.5).

From the SEO point of view, separate domains for separate langauges are good. Search engine need to have different content (different languages) under different URLs. You could also use example.com/[lang]/ format, which doesn't require registering multiple domains.

Comment: I do not quite understand this. Are you saying, it is better having an www.example.com/de and www.example.com/en page for SEO purposes? Or should I have a www.example.com in german and link to www.example.com/en if the browser is english? 

And what does it mean having an Accept-Lanugage paramether? If someone comes from France, what does this mean for them?

Sorry that I need longer to understand this...

Comment: No, I mean, it's better having example.com/de than serve both English and German content under example.com.
Accept-Language header can be processed on server site to do redirection there, without a need for client-side code.